# IIS7 module: not showing in feature view?

Tags: iis-7, rewrite

I just installed the URL rewrite module in II7, rewrite_2.0_rtw_x64.
The module is working, I can modify manually web.config. 
However in the web site "feature view" there is no "rewrite url" icon, so I'm not able to use the nice GUI to edit and create rules...
Any idea, apart stopping/restarting IIS, the PC etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, restarting the PC the url rewrite module appears.